# Send FMC Message to a topic chunk by chunk

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

We have a website that works with two million users. When we have new events on the website we send an FCM notification to our user's mobile app. But the website does not have enough resources for lots of users at once.

Can we send FCM messages to a topic chunk by chunk or deliberately decrease the fanout rate and put a delay between each fanout?
What is your suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to control the fanout rate of topics in Firebase Cloud Messaging.

The only options I can think of are to:

- Create a number of more specific topics (e.g. `topic-001`, `topic-002`, ... `topic-100`), subscribing each client to one of the topics randomly (a form of sharding), and then sending a message to each topic in turn with a delay in between them.
- Using a `data` only message, and delaying the display in your application code by a random amount.
- No longer using topics but delivering straight to FCM tokens in your code, so that you fully control when each individual message gets sent.